# How to parse JSON data which comes from Service

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
"{items:[{"$param":"PostCode","$value":["560059"],"type":"String","mode":"IN"},{"$param":"Address1stLine","$value":["Bangalore"],"type":"String","mode":"IN"},{"$param":"LastName","$value":["Ingale"],"type":"String","mode":"IN"},{"$param":"mail_To","$value":["atul.ingale@mindtree.com"],"type":"String","mode":"IN"},{"$param":"Gender","$value":["Male"],"type":"String","mode":"IN"},{"$param":"Complaint","$value":[""],"type":"String","mode":"IN"},{"$param":"Forename","$value":["Atul"],"type":"String","mode":"IN"},{"$param":"XRayComments","$value":[""],"type":"String","mode":"INOUT"},{"$param":"BloodTestComments","$value":[""],"type":"String","mode":"INOUT"},{"$param":"NeedBloodTest","$value":["false"],"type":"Boolean","mode":"INOUT"},{"$param":"NeedXRay","$value":["false"],"type":"Boolean","mode":"INOUT"}]}"
```

How to parse above data which is coming from REST service response, in both Javascript and angularjs

Comment: JSON.parse(YOUR_TEXT);

Comment: Something wrong with source if those outer quotes exist

Comment: I found answer in
Just use the following line
`var data = your double quoted JSON string
var myJSON = eval( data );`

Comment: JSON.parse(jsonData);

Answer (score 0):

Angularjs:

```
var yourData = angular.fromJson(yourJsontext)
```

JavaScript:

```
var yourData = JSON.parse(yourJsontext)
```

Comment: ""{items:[{\"$param\":\"PostCode\",\"$value\":[\"560059\"],\"type\":\"String\",\"mode\":\"IN\"},{\"$param\":\"Address1stLine\",\"$value\":[\"Bangalore\"],\"type\":\"String\",\"mode\":\"IN\"},{\"$param\":\"LastName\",\"$value\":[\"Ingale\"],\"type\":\"String\",\"mode\":\"IN\"}]}""

Comment: Umm u need to remove "- marks around ur json. json starts with { and ends with }. To test ur json is in proper format u can go test it in: http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/

Comment: It appears ur returning string from rest instead of json.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse

Answer (score -1):

If you are using angular just use it:

```
angular.toJson(yourobj, pretty);
```

Comment: I have tried this solution but I am not able to use outcome of this in ng-repeat , instead it is converging like this

Comment: ""{items:[{\"$param\":\"PostCode\",\"$value\":[\"560059\"],\"type\":\"String\",\"mode\":\"IN\"},{\"$param\":\"Address1stLine\",\"$value\":[\"Bangalore\"],\"type\":\"String\",\"mode\":\"IN\"},{\"$param\":\"LastName\",\"$value\":[\"Ingale\"],\"type\":\"String\",\"mode\":\"IN\"}]}""

Comment: @VittalKamkar what are you using in ng-repeat

Comment: @VittalKamkar here is i tried form your json https://plnkr.co/edit/KXgEhVWq8dIL6Ruiohkk?p=preview

Comment: Thanks for your effort but you have manually excluded in your double quotes while declaring a scope variable $scope.myData.
Could you please see my string format which contains double quote in the beginning of string.

Comment: `"{items:[{"$param":"PostCode","$value":["560059"],"type":"String","mode":"IN"},{"$param":"Address1stLine","$value":["Bangalore"],"type":"String","mode":"IN"},{"$param":"LastName","$value":["Ingale"],"type":"String","mode":"IN"},{"$param":"mail_To","$value":["atul.ingale@mindtree.com"],"type":"String","mode":"IN"},{"$param":"Gender","$value":["Male"],"type":"String","mode":"IN"},{{"$param":"XRayComments","$value":[""],"type":"String","mode":"INOUT"},{"$param":"NeedXRay","$value":["false"],"type":"Boolean","mode":"INOUT"}]}"`